# Check if a Mail folder exists using Zend Mail

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I check if an email folder exists using Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap, theres a createFOlder, renameFOlder and removeFolder and also a getFOlders but not exactly any fixed method to query if a certain mail folder exists? The GetFOlders returns a humonogous tree of folders to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not worked with `Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap` before, but from what I can glean from the source, this should do the trick:

```
/**
 * Checks if a folder exists by name.
 * @param Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap $imapObj Our IMAP object.
 * @param string $folder The name of the folder to check for.
 * @return boolean True if the folder exists, false otherwise.
 */
function folderExists(Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap $imapObj, $folder) {
    try {
        $imapObj->selectFolder($folder);
    } catch (Zend_Mail_Storage_Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you want to preserve the current folder through the check, it gets a bit trickier, of course:

```
/**
 * Checks if a folder exists by name.
 * @param Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap $imapObj Our IMAP object.
 * @param string $folder The name of the folder to check for.
 * @return boolean True if the folder exists, false otherwise.
 * @throws Zend_Mail_Storage_Exception if the current folder cannot be restored.
 */
function folderExists(Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap $imapObj, $folder) {
    $result    = true;
    $oldFolder = $imapObj->getCurrentFolder();
    try {
        $imapObj->selectFolder($folder);
    } catch (Zend_Mail_Storage_Exception $e) {
        $result = false;
    }
    $imapObj->selectFolder($oldFolder);
    return $result;
}
```

(Your preference of how to deal with that situation may, of course, vary, that one is rather sloppy.)